# Good way to declare trees in prolog?

Tags: tree, prolog

I am working with trees (general trees, not limited to binary) in prolog. From the small snippets of code I have seen, though it's easy to define traversals etc. on the tree, it's not easy to define an instance of  a tree. What would be a good way to do this? Also, how should I try to include single-attribute values with each node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your comment "But the problem is that the whole tree has to go in one line": This is not the case. You can also use several lines to construct a tree, for example:

```
tree(Tree) :-
    Tree = tree(Root, [Child,Leaf3]).
    Child = tree(Node1, [Leaf1,Leaf2]),
    Leaf1 = tree(Node2, []),
    Leaf2 = tree(Node3, []),
    Leaf3 = tree(Node4, []).
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this homework?

The simple way to represent an arbitrary tree structure, IMHO, would be to represent each node as something something like:

```
tree(Data,[ChildNode_1,...,ChildNode_n]).
```

Leaf nodes would look like:

```
tree(Data,[]).
```

A binary tree, being slightly specialized, might look like

```
tree(Data,LeftChild,RightChild).
```

with the atom nil representing a non-existent child node, so its leaf nodes would look like

```
tree(Data,nil,nil).
```

And a node with only a left child like

```
tree(Data,LeftChild,nil).
```

Node data can be any arbitrary structure. Perhaps you want it to be a key/value pair:

```
tree(kvp(Key,Value),ChildNodes).
```

Comment: But the problem is that the whole tree has to go in one line `tree(ROOT,[tree(NODE1,[tree(NODE2,[]),tree(NODE3,[])], tree(NODE4, [])])`. That becomes very annoying.

Comment: Yes. Building recursive data structures is...recursive. Not much you could do about that. Add line breaks and formatting so it looks more like a tree.